# How can I select the second minimal value within a inner join?

Tags: mysql, subquery, max, inner-join, min

I have this query

```
select c.id, c.name, c.email, c.totalpets, min(p.date_created) as first_order,
min(p.weight) as min_weight_bought,
max(p.weight) as max_weight_bought,
count(p.ordernumber) as total_orders
from orders p
inner join customers c
on p.customer_id = c.id
where p.approved = 1
and c.totalpets >= 1
group by c.id
having total_orders > 1
```

Note that first_order gives me the first result of the row, right? I am trying to get customer first order and customer second order. How can i do that within this inner join?

Thanks

Comment: You should only select aggregates and columns appearing in the `GROUP BY` clause, hence the query should read `SELECT c.id, MIN(p.date_created) FROM orders ... GROUP BY c.id`.

Comment: I don't know if I get it. You mean a subquery with these arguments?

Comment: No, I wasn't giving an answer, I was just correcting the problem with your original query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c1.id,
       c1.name,
       c1.email,
       c1.totalpets,
       p1.date_created
FROM orders p1
INNER JOIN customers c1
    ON p1.customer_id = c1.id
WHERE 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM orders p2
    INNER JOIN customers c2
        ON p2.customer_id = c2.id
    WHERE c2.id = c1.id AND p2.date_created <= p1.date_created
) <= 2 
ORDER BY c1.id;
```

Here is a running demo which shows a simplified version of the above query (and simplified data set) in action:

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Tim, I will try this. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @HenriqueM. My query seems to be working, insofar that it returns the lowest two creation dates per customer.  If you want other aggregates in your result (e.g. min and max weight bought), then you can try joining a second query to the above one, as my query does not use aggregation.

Comment: I have no clue for making it happen :( 
To me it appears to be giving the two results in rows, as I expected to have it in columns. Also, how can I add the desired columns which I had back in my query to this without messing around with yours?

Comment: Here is a Fiddle which gives the first and second order dates in a single record: [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b56c95/3).  For your other columns, as I have already mentioned, just join a second query to this result.

Comment: You saved my life. I managed how to include the others columns, just one filter that I don't see how: filter only clientes that have > 1 orders, this way the first and the second order should not be the same

Comment: Change the outer `WHERE` condition to `WHERE (...) = 2` instead of `<=2`.  This will force the query to retain only customers with at least two order.  Here is another fiddle for you: [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2ece/1).

Comment: Awesome! You bet!